# adding recurring events to non-recurring table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
event
- id
- date_start
- number_hours
- date_end 
- specialist_id / specialist assigned to this event.
```

A User chooses the date the event will start and the number of hours it will last. Right now all of these events are non-recurring, but I want to add the possibility of recurring events.

How can I do so in a well-designed way?
I want to be able to expand this design to not only support weekly and monthly events, but also every sunday, saturday, or other recurring type of event ... thanks

I was thinking about the following

event

```
- id
- date_start
- recurring / whether the event is recurring or not
- weekly / (if repeats every 1 week, this will be 1, if repeats every 2 weeks, this number will be 2)
- monthly / (if repeats every 1 month, this will be 1, if repeats every 2 months, this number will be 2)
- last_occurred_date / date the event last occurred (if non-recurring, this equals date_start, if recurring, it does not)
- next_occurred_date / date when the event is supposed to occur next.
- specialist_id / what specialist took this event
```

So if the user adds an event for 10/1/2012, recurring every month, then the following entry is added to the table:

```
date_start: 10/1/2012, recurring: 1, weekly: 0, monthly: 1 (it occurs every 1 month), last_occurred_Date: 10/1/2012, next_occurred_date: 11/1/2012)
```

And I have cron job that basically goes through all the recurring events (where event.recurring = 1 and adds entries to the event table for new events coming up.)

So the next date for the event is 11/1/2012. The following entry is added:

```
id: 1 date_start: 11/1/2012 recurring: 0
```

The reason why I add an entry for each date the recurring event takes place is because I have to assign a specialist to each event. So specialists get emails with a link where they can sign up for each event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking 2 tables for the event and some others for participants and recurrence. 1 table keeps the event "template", another the actual event instances, and potentially a 3rd to keep track of recurrence.

- event_defaults

  - id
  - event_name
  - event_duration (INT seconds)
  - location
- default_participants

  - user_id
  - event_defaults_id (foriegn key to event_defaults.id, never NULL)
  - (dual primary key between user_id and events_default.id)
- event_recurrence

  - foriegn key to event_defaults.id
  - recurrence_unit (ENUM of day, week, month, quarter, year)
  - recurrence_multiplier (INT for how many days, weeks, months to recur)
  - start_date
  - recur_until
- events

  - event_id
  - defaults_id (foriegn key to event_defaults.id, maybe NULL)
  - name
  - start_time (timestamp)
  - end_time (timestamp)
  - location
- participants

  - user_id
  - event_id (foriegn key to events.id)
  - (dual primary key between user_id and events.id)

The idea is for your recurring events, you create an entry into the **event_defaults** table and the recurrence info into **event_recurrence**. Then you create an *instance* of every template as an actual events in **events**. The user can then define some participants he wants for each event (by default). All one-time events get inserted directly into **events** with the foriegn key to event_defaults.id being NULL.

When the event recurrence runs out, then you can delete the entry in **event_defaults** and keep the record for the events that happened in **events**. You can have kron prune these guys out after so many days, archive them into another table, or maybe even maintain a partition on the **events** table for events that have expired.

The nice thing is by keeping the template and the actual instance of each event separate, you can modify individual events while still keeping the template the same. So say for example the Weekly Office Meeting is happening at some restaurant this week instead of the office conference room. Now you can just update the location for the appropriate instance of the event in **events** without changing the weekly template.

Additionally, you can assign a default specialist for each event and if they need to switch out with some other specialist for whatever reason, you just edit the individual event instance instead of the template.

Additionally, your kron job can create new events for up to recur_until or .... 10 years? Whatever arbitrary interval you decide. Prolly not a good idea to create instances for recurring events till the end of time.